# HTTPS Load Balancer + Cloud Run links not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, gcp-load-balancer

We have a load balancer with a URL map that points to back-end Cloud run services. When we just use cloud run without a load balancer all the assets load as expected. (e.g links to the cloud run service are correct.

**When we put the service behind a load balancer we have some weird issues on the links returned from the backend service.**

When we hit the load balancer with this path `https://custom.domain.com/hello-no-auth` we hit the backend service but all the links returned from the service has the wrong paths. The return links from the service miss the URL path we defined in the URL map. For example, icons will come back with his URL
`https://custom.domain.com/assets/icon.svg`
but we expected they would come back with
`https://custom.domain.com/hello-no-auth/assets/icon.svg`

Also `https://custom.domain.com` is not the real domain but just for demonstration

Comment: Can you share your configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies this was an error with the return links for the assets in the backend service.

To be clear this was not an issue with GCP but the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not implemented [URL rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite) in your project.